# Primary decomposition theorem verification

Tags: linear-algebra

Recently I reviewed linear algebra and here is a theorem I want to verify. (I just want to know whether this is really true or not). I'm asking since this statement is more general than that in usual abstract algebra texts.

In the following theorem, $V$ denotes a nonzero finite-dimensional vector space over $F$, $T$ denotes a linear operator on $V$, $C_T$ denotes the characteristic polynomial of $T$.

> Theorem.
>
> Let $\phi$ be a monic prime polynomial such that $\phi | C_T$.
>
> Then, there exist nonzero vectors $x_1,...,x_n$ such that $\{x\in V: \exists (k\in \mathbb{N}) (\phi(T))^k(x)=0\}=\oplus_{i=1}^n Z(x_i;T)$
>
> Moreover, if $y_1,...,y_m$ are another set of nonzero vectors such that $\{x\in V: \exists (k\in \mathbb{N}) (\phi(T))^k(x)=0\}=\oplus Z(y_i;T)$, then $n=m$ and there exists $\sigma\in S_n$ such that $dim(Z(y_i;T))=dim(Z(x_{\sigma(i)};T))$.

Is this statement really true?

(Proof is done through Jordan canonical form by viewing $\{x\in V: \exists (k\in \mathbb{N}) (\phi(T))^k(x)=0\}$ as a generalized eigenspace of $\phi(T)$.)

Comment: What does $Z(x_i;T)$ mean?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen T-cyclic subspace generated by $x_i$. (i.e. $Span(\{T_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$)

Comment: How do you plan to use Jordan form for irreducible (prime) factors $\phi$ of with $\deg\phi>1$, for which no Jordan form exists?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Set $U=\phi(T)$. Then, $\{x\in V: \exists (k\in \mathbb{N}) (\phi(T))^k(x)=0\}=\{x\in V: \exists (k\in\mathbb{N}) U^k(x)=0\}$.Hence, $0$ is an eigenvalue of $U$. So we can decompose $\{x\in V: \exists (k\in \mathbb{N}) (\phi(T))^k(x)=0\}$ into direct sum of $U$-cyclic subspaces.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Then restrict $U$ on that set.

Comment: $U$-cyclic subspaces will not be $T$-stable (especially if $U=0$, which is a major case here); I don't understand that argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you seem to be saying is that for finite dimensional vector spaces $W$ equipped with a linear operator $T$ satisfying $\phi^k(T)=0$ for some ireducible polynomial $\phi$ (that is what your expressions in braces amount to), they can be decomposed as $F[X]$-modules into a direct sum of cyclic submodules isomorphic to $K[X]/(\phi^i)$ (with possibly varying $i$), and that the number of factors isomorphic to $K[X]/(\phi^i)$ is independent of the decomposition, for each $i$ (so that one can find a dimension-preserving mathcing of the cyclic summands for any two decompositions).

This is true; an easy consequence of the [structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain), applied to this special case.

Comment: So are you restricting $V$ to $\{x\in V: \exists (k\in \mathbb{N}) (\phi(T))^k(x)=0\}$ and applying the structure theorem?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing. Because the statement you give only says something about that subspace, one might as well forget the rest. And since this module is already has a primary ideal as annihilator, the invariant factor decomposition and primary decompositions give the same type of (non-unique) decomposition into cyclic submodules.